# Flutter CameraPreview is blurry, noisy, and zoomed in

Tags: android, flutter, dart, camera, android-camera

I have a Google Pixel 3 and am using Flutter's [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) plugin at version `0.8.1`.

`CameraPreview` is blurry, noisy, zoomed in, and generally looks worse than Android's camera app.

Android Camera App:
[image]

Flutter CameraPreview:
[image]

This is how I'm instantiating the `CameraController`:

```
final cameras = await availableCameras();
final controller = CameraController(
  cameras[0],
  ResolutionPreset.veryHigh,
  enableAudio: false,
  imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420,
);
```

I tried all 4 cameras:

- Camera 0 is on the front and is the one in question
- Camera 1-3 is on the back and they are all the same. Their quality is similar to Android's Camera App.

Anyone run into this issue?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Made any progress resolving this?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: Woof, still no fix? This seems like it may possibly be caused by an incorrect aspect ratio. OP, did you still have the same issue after the pictures were taken?

Comment: I have the same problem. Camera plugin doesn't allow to take a photo normally because it take too much time to focus (several seconds), and image stream makes photo blurry even in preview mode.

Answer (score -2):

try using the [image_picker](http://image_picker:%20%5E0.7.4) plugin, you can adjust the image quality and resolution easily.

```
void pickImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front,
      imageQuality: 100,
      maxWidth: 5000,
      maxHeight: 5000,
    );
    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
      print(_image);
    });
  }
```

Comment: That won't work. I'm looking to show the camera feed in a widget.